# Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I try to connect to servers or join up on lan worlds in Minecraft it says "Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game)". Multiplayer used to work fine but now keeps coming up with this error. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your game? (had to ask)

Comment: Are u using a cracked launcher if you are it will automatically reject you from the game because mojang wont allow it!

Comment: Is there any way to restart the session without reloading Minecraft? Some mod packs take tens of minutes to launch, so this would be a real help.

Comment: @rakslice: I just stumbled on a Forge mod called [Re-Auth](https://mods.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/237701-reauth) that supposedly does just that.  I have not tried it yet but tempted to because I switch between multiple Internet connections and it's a pain to restart the client every time.

Comment: Can confirm ReAuth, it works really well.

Comment: I just had this issue and **turning off my VPN fixed the problem** when restarting minecraft and logging in and out didn't help.

Comment: Either be online on client or switch server to off-line mode (`online-mode=false` in `server.properties`).

Answer (score 35):

Just as the error says your session ID, what you log in with, is invalid. This usually happens when you log in to your account and then have a new instance of minecraft and log in again without closing down the old one. The old session ID is invalidated as soon as the new connection is made. This will give you the error above when you attempt to log into a server as it will only have the new Session ID.

Restarting your client is the only way to get a new session ID as it will wipe out whatever it thinks the new one is and truly give you a new one. (Restart your client by quitting the game, **closing and reopening the launcher**, and then starting the game again)

If this problem persists, and you have already tried the possible causes (e.g. firewall, VPN), then try contacting Mojang customer support.

Comment: How do you restart your client

Comment: Close it and start it up again.. This will happen every time you have two instances of minecraft running, the older one will always have an outdated session id.

Comment: Great answer. Restarting the launcher in addition to Minecraft itself was the key for me, and you even put that part in bold! Thanks!

Comment: @Mir Glad to help... Its not always obvious its the launcher that actually does the login, but it is.

Comment: In my case I restarted the client too fast, so it didn't work. Closing and *leaving* everything closed for 30 seconds, and then starting, worked. Guessing the launcher reuses something if you're too fast about it

Comment: Technically you do not have to "restart the launcher" - if the launcher is left open, you would only need to make it sign in again. But the only way I know to do this is, if you have multiple accounts, change the logged-in account then change it back. So restarting the launcher is probably faster than this anyways.