# Direct connect to lan causes: failed to login invalid session

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So there is something strange going on. I bought a new router and it was already configured(with passwords etc.). When I try to open lan, and connect with another computer (we are connected on the same Wifi) it doesnt detect a LAN server! Thats a bit strange because past week i played with two computers on the other router and it work perfectly.

It first image you can see that through `ipconfig` I was able to added a server (192.168.....:xxxx).

[image]

But when I try to connect, this happens:

[image]
(of course I tried to relaunch the minecraft)

I dont know where the problems is. I changed firewall settings many times(read from this forum that this can help), nothing changed. 
PS: i prefer not to use HAMACHI

Something similar : [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error)

Comment: You bought a router, and it was already configured? You didn't buy it new?

Comment: Make sure there is no policy or restriction on your wifi-router blocking Minecraft. There's something called "Intra BSS Traffic Blocking", maybe you should check on that. Also check the firewall on your computer.

Comment: When you say you get a new router, and it was already configured, where did you get it from? if it's second hand, it's possible there are settings in place causing this issue... i'd find the manual for the router and look to reset it to defaults first. If you got it from your ISP, it *should* be ok, but it may be worth speaking to your ISP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

1. Start Minecraft on both the computer being connected to (Host) and the one connecting (Player)
2. On the Host computer under Singleplayer, start the world you want the Player to connect to.
3. Press Esc and click 'Open to LAN' and configure the settings there, then click 'Start LAN World'

   - This will output 'Local game hosted on port XXXXX
4. On the Payer computer, make sure you're connected to the same WiFi as the Host, then click Multiplayer.

   - It will say 'Scanning for games on your local network'
5. If set up correctly, the game will appear at the bottom of the server list with the username of the Host.

Hope this works for you.