# "failed to login: Invalid session (try restarting your game) minecraft error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

[image: screenshot of error]whenever i try to log into any server with my premium account on the official launcher this error always pops up. i've tried restarting the game, deleting the game and even gone as far as resetting my laptop but nothing works. i'm currently using windows 10 and this has only recently been occurring and i'm wondering why this is happening since the cracked version works perfectly fine on my brothers laptop. any suggestions??

UPDATE: i have found a work around solution that works and enables me to log in fine without this error message. using a VPN (cyberghost 6) i connect to another IP and log into my mojang account from the launcher startup.

Comment: Close the launcher and close the game

Comment: @LyricsBot He/She even deleted everything on his laptop. Everything that can be restarted was restarted.

Comment: @tamia Maybe wait a few seconds after loading the server list before clicking on a server? That solves a similar problem for me.

Comment: Also: There are no premium accounts. If you bought something that said "premium", it's the wrong one. There are just normal accounts, they cost something like 20$.

Comment: @tamia log out of minecraft then log back in maybe?

Comment: @Fabian i have bought an official minecraft account and since have migrated it to a mojang account as a solution (didn't fix anything). i have also tried waiting a few minutes before clicking on the server but the same message continues to pop up, thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the game and the installer and download the installer again from https://minecraft.net/en-us/

Then retry, if you still have problems, email mojang ( https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new )