# Invalid Session (Try restarting your game) error in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been trying to connect to multiplayer servers, which I could connect to just fine just a few hours ago, but now I'm getting the error message "Failed to login: Invalid session (Try restarting your game.)" I've restarted my game multiple times, and even restarted my PC, but still the same error. I need help.

Comment: What have you tried outside of restarting your PC and are you using the default vanilla launcher / game?

Answer (score -2):

You may have signed in from another computer or location. Try logging out, then back in. If this doesn't help, please refer to [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)