# Minecraft Invalid Session glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

This glitch is happening to me on 5 accounts, not just one account so I do not think it is my account.

- First I open the minecraft launcher and it makes me sign in.
- Says I have incorrect password

  ---
- I go to minecraft.net and sign in there. When I sign in there, it just refreshes the sign-in page instead of actually logging me in.
- I go back to the launcher and try to sign in again with the same password. It works.
- I click play, minecraft loads.
- I try to join mineplex and get an invalid session.
- I close the game and the launcher
- I open the launcher and try to sign in
- Incorrect password.

Repeat from separation line

This glitch is keeping me from joining any server whatsoever.

Things I have tried:
- Re-installing minecraft
- different accounts
- restarting java
- redownloading java
- launch with vanilla minecraft
- launch with 5zig
- launch with labymod
- launch with badlion
- launch on latest version
- launch on older versions
- Password change
- contacting minecraft support (They never responded :/)

Sometimes I am able to log in after many attempts and join the server and I have no idea what the cause is. As soon as I quit the server I get an invalid session again.

I am thinking that it has something to do with my internet or my computer because otherwise, my accounts wouldn't all be having the same issue.
Someone, please help me figure this out, I'm on the verge of factory resetting my pc.

I also made a youtube video that will help to understand the problem:

Comment: I don't think linking videos with swear words in them is forbidden, but it's definitely questionable...

Comment: Do you have a support case ID? Also, how long did you wait so far?

Comment: You are not the only one. I have been having this issue for over a week now. Back in the day, this meant someone had credentials to your minecraft account and just logged into it. Something is wrong with Minecraft's session servers for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error)