# Minecraft Invalid session on my own server

Tags: hosting, minecraft-forge

i created a minecraft-hosting.pro paid server for forge 1.15.2 and am unable to login to it in multiplayer. it shows that my server is online and I am running forge 1.15.2 on launcher. however i keep getting the invalid session (try restarting your game) every time i try to login. i can login to my bfs server, but not my own. Please help.

i have done the java 8 update, and can now no longer open Minecraft forge 1.15.2, however i can open latest release 1.1.5.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error)