# What can I do when getting 'Invalid session' error in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Today, out of the blue, I got an error saying:

> Invalid session (try restarting your game and launcher).

Usually, I can just restart the game and the error will go away, but today I've been getting the error multiple times, even after logging out of the launcher, signing out and back in, and even reinstalling Minecraft, but nothing works.

What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks any relevance for future viewers and shows low research effort (obvious server outage).

Comment: @aphid Why is that obvious? And why is this question irrelevant for future users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Login : Invalid session (Try restarting your game) Minecraft Error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/failed-to-login-invalid-session-try-restarting-your-game-minecraft-error)

Comment: @aphid that's not a good reason to close a question, you should instead downvote the question instead. You should downvote any question that "Does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Answer (score 1):

The Minecraft Session Servers are down right now.
The only thing you can do now is wait...